# Is scalar product a well-conditioned operation?

Tags: numerical-methods

I'm reading a course and one of the exercises is about establishing whether scalar product is a well-conditioned operation. Here's their solution. They disturb each element of the vector by multiplying it by $(1+\alpha_{i})$ where $\alpha$ is really small.
[image]

And when one of the elements of the sum is equal to the negative of the rest of the elements, then the last part of the inequalities goes to $\infty$.

But how does that prove, that scalar product is poorly-conditioned? Surely I could put $f(x)=x$ and say that $f(x)<\infty$ but that doesn't mean that that calculating such a simple function is a poorly conditioned operation. How is that different here?